# Identifying feature class permissions in Oracle ArcSDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, security

I created a new Feature Class, and I assigned some users **SELECT** privileges to that Feature Class.  I want to look at the list of users that I have assigned privileges to, how do I do that?

**Updated**

Is there a GUI application to do this?

Answer (score 3):

via SQL from shell:

```sql
select grantee, privilege 
from dba_tab_privs 
where table_name = 'FEATURECLASS_NAME' and owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME';
```

this will give you the list of users that have privs to that feature class's business table. if you granted privs via arccatalog, then the privs will be for the entire feature class.

Comment: I was hoping to have a GUI app for this, but still good info.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a couple of years since i've used oracle and ArcSDE, but I think I used some Oracle SQL(sqlplus from shell) to figure out what was granted.  I don't have the SQL, but it would be something along the lines of: http://oraclepitstop.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/sql-script-to-list-oject-privileges-granted-to-a-particular-user/

```sql
select grantor || ‘ granted ‘ || privilege || ‘ on ‘ || table_name || ‘ owned by ‘|| owner || ‘ to ‘|| grantee 
from dba_tab_privs 
where grantee like upper(‘&GRANTEE_NAME’) 
order by privilege;
```

The [GDB Toolset](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/gdbt/index.html) might also have this functionality, but it was just as easy(and faster) for me to  set up a batch file to query the info. But you do need to sort through the various sde/gdb/adds&deletes tables that will get reported back.

Comment: I don't see an option in GDB to see Privileges.  :)

Do you know of another GUI app that might have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In response to the update in the question

> Is there a GUI application to do this?

Starting from ArcGIS 10.0 (released late 2010, so after this question was originally asked) you can view and modify permissions on a feature class from ArcCatalog.  To do this you must be the owner of the feature class.

In ArcCatalog (or the ArcMap Catalog window):

1. Browse to the feature class in your geodatabase connection
2. Right-click on the feature class and select Manage > Privileges

[image]

This will open the Privileges dialog which will show you the users that have access to that feature class, and what privileges they have.  You can also grant/revoke permissions and add/remove users access.

[image]